# Syncfusion Rich Text Editor in Blazor taking time to load

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, syncfusion, syncfusion-blazor

I am using a sync fusion rich text editor and in the model I am using string property to bind the value, the problem which I am facing is, it's taking 8-10 seconds to load even after the entire form loads and I have to wait till the rich text editor loads completely to do any further actions in the form.

Comment: Hi, you need to provide more information such as demo code that demonstrates your problem and shows what you've done to isolate your problem to the richtexteditor.